# Django content type table data migration while upgrading from 1.6 to 2.2 with legacy database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations, django-contenttypes, legacy-database

I am Upgrading my django project from version 1.6 to 2.2.
I'm already having a legacy database with lot of **generic relations** in the project.

Can anyone help to how should the **django_content_type** table should be populated.
If I will go for new migrations, the content_type table data may be corrupted and there is chance to break all the generic relations.

Should I use the same data of the **django_content_type** table from the exisiting db and fake the initial migrations. Will it work??
Can django handle the rest of the part? as the relations will not break?
Is there any chance to occur a  problem for future migrations ??

Or

Is there any other method for creating entries in the
table**django_content_type**?

Also, any documentation or links regarding this could possibly a great help!

Thanks in Advance!!!